# Setting and retrieving objects in an array

Tags: arrays, object

I'm trying to store an array of simple objects and then retrieve them.  For some reason the pName element in my object always comes back as "default".  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  personID comes back with the expected value.

```
var phys = {pName:"default",
            personID:0};

var aGroupPhys = [];  // Clear the array
for (var i = 0; i < data.MD_LIST.Q.length; i++) {
    //phys.pNname = data.MD_LIST.Q[i].PHYS_NAME;
    phys.pNname = "STEVE"
    phys.personID = data.MD_LIST.Q[i].PERSON_ID;
    aGroupPhys.push(phys);
    alert(i + " Name: " + aGroupPhys[i].pName + "  personID: " + aGroupPhys[i].personID);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please add language tag

Comment: Typo: Remove the extra `n` in `phys.pNname = "STEVE"`.

Comment: Also notice that you keep adding *the same* object to the array. You'll end up with an array of a number of identical entries. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: I just noticed that.  Removing it solved the problem.  Guess I need a new pair of glasses.

Comment: I add the same object but with different values.  How would I create a new object for each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.  Below is the correct code.

```
var phys = {}           
var aGroupPhys = [];  // Clear the array

for (var i = 0; i < data.MD_LIST.Q.length; i++) {
    phys = new Object();

    phys.pName = data.MD_LIST.Q[i].PHYS_NAME;
    //phys.pName = "STEVE"
    phys.personID = data.MD_LIST.Q[i].PERSON_ID;
    aGroupPhys.push(phys);
    //alert(i + " Name: " + aGroupPhys[i].pName + "  personID: " + aGroupPhys[i].personID);
}

for (var i = 0; i < aGroupPhys.length; i++) {
    alert(aGroupPhys[i].pName);
}
```